# ngModel is not working on <div> tag using contenteditable and have html as an input

Tags: angular

I am trying to bind my input, which is string having html content in it.
app.component.ts has 'content' variable

```
content : string = "<p>This is my editable data.</p><p>Two way binding is   not getting applied on it.</p>
public validateProfile(content){
console.log(content);
}
```

app.component.html has following code

```
<div contentEditable="true" [innerHTML]="content" [(ngModel)]="content"></div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" (click)="validateProfile(content)">Validate Profile</button>
```

I am able to edit the content inside  tag. As my input is html data in string format , I can't bind it to input tag. 
Can someone please suggest how to apply 2 way binding with contenteditable= true on div or span.

Comment: ng-model wont work with contenteditable.

Comment: ngModel work with text boxes `INPUT, TEXTAREA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

**template**

```
<div contenteditable="true" [innerHTML]="content" (input)="contentNew=$event.target.textContent"></div>
<br/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" (click)="validateProfile(contentNew)">Validate Profile</button>
```

**typescript**

```
  contentNew: string;
  content : string = "<p>This is my editable data.</p><p>Two way binding is   not getting applied on it.</p>";

  public validateProfile(content){
    this.contentNew = content;
    console.log(content);
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtzzhu?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: @Pallavi Can you close this answer ?

Comment: I can't close it as I do not have enough reputation points required to close the question.

Comment: As $event.target.textContent gives the content. Eg : That will return the text as 
    'This is my editable data.Two way binding is   not getting applied on it' ,  
But can we bind the entire html string which could return as '<p>This is my editable data.</p><p>Two way binding is   not getting applied on it.</p>'?

I have tried innerHTML, outerHTML as a properties of $event.target , but those are returning content only.

Do you have any idea about any property which could bind the entire html content ?

Comment: @Pallavi try like the following link :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtzzhu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts and check the console.log it will be pass entire html element

Comment: Now entire content is getting reflected.But, in this case, there are 2 html controls - 1. for editing (div) 2. for display (p).

Both these things have to happen on same control, either <p> or <div>,  like is used to happen in previous solution provided by you.

Comment: It is working with $event.target.outerHTML now.

I guess it didn't work due to browser's cache issue earlier.

Thank you so much for your inputs and suggestion.That was really very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To bind with a value do this

```
<div contenteditable=true (input)="content= $event.target.innerHTML; htmlContentChange($event.target.innerHTML)" (contentChange)="someFunction()"></div>
```

In your component

```
export class myComponent {
    @Input() content;
    @Output() contentChange = new EventEmitter(); // for two way binding

   /*
   * update html on changes in content editable
   */
   htmlContentChange(value) {
      this.htmlChange.emit(value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following way and its working fine.
try it out

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="content"/>
<div contentEditable="true" [(innerHTML)]="content" ></div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" (click)="validateProfile(content)">Validate Profile</button>
```

Comment: This works but content comes as an html tags.

It has to get displayed as user friendly text.

eg. It is getting displayed as <p>Some Text. </p>

Rather it should get displayed as : Some Text.

Moreover, editing has to happen on div tag only instead of input tag.