# passing ngmodel throug a div element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular8

I have a value in my table. I am trying to pass the particular cell value to typescript. But when I try it using **ngmodel** and when I debug it gets undefined. The ngmodel value **qty** was assigned as number in typescript and it is a number. The stackblitz is only for refernce in reality I am getting a value from a td tag which I got from a list

Stackblitz sample one:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sundu2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

My code:

```
   <td>
      <div *ngIf="data === 'RARE' ; else notype" style="cursor: pointer;"
       (click)="View()" [(ngModel)]="qty" name="fieldName" ngDefaultControl>{{ list.value}}</div>
       <ng-template #notype (click)="View()"> {{currentvalue}}</ng-template>
   </td>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093360/ngmodel-is-not-working-on-div-tag-using-contenteditable-and-have-html-as-an-in

Comment: I have tried that one already didnt work. I have posted a a sample stackblitz @uiTeam324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `(click)` inside the html template

```
<td>
   <div *ngIf="data === 'RARE' ; else notype" style="cursor: pointer;"
    (click)="setQty(list.value)" name="fieldName" ngDefaultControl>{{ list.value}}</div>
     <ng-template #notype (click)="View()"> {{currentvalue}}</ng-template>
</td>
```

and in the component

```
setQty(val: number) {
  this.qty = val;
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gavpqc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

For more details see: https://angular.io/guide/event-binding

Comment: NO. pass it as a number in html. Assign number to qty in ts and then get that value in qty in ts @sevic

Comment: Imagine I am getting those values from a table cell

Comment: At which moment do you want to assign the value of the table to the `qty`? When clicking the element?

Comment: Yeah exactly when clicking the element the value in that td tag should pass to the qty variable in typescript @sevic

Answer (score 0):

try [innerHTML] instead of [(ngModel)] :

```
<td>
  <div *ngIf="data === 'RARE' ; else notype" style="cursor: pointer;"
   (click)="View()" [innerHTML]="qty" name="fieldName" ngDefaultControl></div>
```